# Trying to get HREF with Selenium and Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

cant get the hrefs from my web element using **.getAttribute("href")**.  I can get it to work on single variable but not when its looping through my array.

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

(async function example() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    try {
        // Navigate to webscraper.io
        await driver.get('https://webscraper.io/test-sites');

        // Scrape links
        let links = await driver.findElements(By.xpath('//*[@class="row test-site"]/div/h2/a'))
        
        // loop through links and print
        console.log('\nFound ' + links.length + ' Links total.\n')  
        for (let index = 0; index < links.length; index++) {
            console.log(links[index].getAttribute("href"));         
        }
    }
    finally{
        driver.quit();
    }
})();
```

I get the following error:

```
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
(node:81217) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:54431
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/eric/Dropbox/Javascript/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:262:15)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:81217) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

added **await** to the console.log line and it worked.

***console.log(await links[index].getAttribute("href"));***